How to create a database diagram for a new SQL Server database having only an sqlproj file
I am creating a new SQL Server database, so in my Visual Studio 2022 solution I have a .sqlproj file containing a collection of .sql files to create tables, foreign key constraints, indexes, etc.
I want to visualize it in a diagram. So far as I can tell, the only way to do this requires that I publish it to create an actual database first.
Is this the only way? Is there no tooling to visualize a database from only the .sqlproj file and the CREATE TABLE etc. statements in its .sql files?

-- Create a temporary database
CREATE DATABASE TempDatabase;
-- Switch to the new database
USE TempDatabase;
-- Execute your schema creation scripts
-- Replace the following lines with actual execution of your .sql files
-- e.g., :r .\path\to\your\create_tables.sql
-- e.g., :r .\path\to\your\create_constraints.sql
-- At this point, you can use SSMS or Visual Studio to generate the diagram
-- Drop the temporary database once done
DROP DATABASE TempDatabase;

You may want to look at DBeaver - it's cross DB vendor too.
